# use of the phrase "in the light of current events"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I would like to use the phrase "in the light of the current events" in the following context:

> This initiative of the government is clear in the light of the current events.

I mean, the initiation of specific bills makes sense against a background of the current political events in the country.

I have doubts about a choice of a correct phrase here. What would you suggest for this context?

1) in the light of the current events
2) against a background of current events
3) another phrase that is perfectly suitable for this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is *in light of current events*, and it means essentially what you suggested: considering what is going on in the most recent news. It's a good fit for the sentence you're using.

I can't find information on the origin of "in light of"; [some sources](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+light+of) just state that it's from the 1680s.

"In the light of" may be correct (although I hadn't heard of it with "the"), but "current events" generally doesn't use a definite article ("the").